# Strange HTTP logs

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

in my apache log i have very lot lines like this :

IP_ADRESS - - [21/Apr/2013:23:05:27 +0200] "\xc8j\xe8_\x8b\xad*x\x98\x0f\xbe\x1a\xf5\xfd\xe3*8\xa3H\x0f\x80\r)o\xe7\xc9\x8b\b \xef\xb7\xe6/\xbd\xae'\x81\xbf\xfb\xd9\x89`F\xe6R\x8bD\xb5bO\xf1\x8e\x\xd6\xe3f" 400 318 "-" "-"

what is this ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone is trying a buffer overflow attack on your web server. The 400 response is BAD REQUEST, which suggests the attack its meaningless to your particular situation and can typically be disregarded as automated background noise; unless you're getting so much traffic that it's affecting your site performance.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing strange here is that it says IP_ADRESS instead of being a real IP or at least being spelled correctly ;)

But seriously, these are botnets doing massive brute force buffer overflow attacks across the internet. This is happening to almost every public webserver, and is quite common. You might wanna use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: thanks, i'm already using fail2ban. but this question is just for understand this attack.